# Append hyperlink to table

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink

I've tried to provide table with `hyperlink`

```
$.each(value, function(index, value){
    $("#myTable > thead").append("<tr><a href='/query/"+value.account_id+"'><td>"+value.first_name+"</td><td>"+value.address1+value.address2+value.address3+"</td></a></tr>");
});
```

which is not working, and I tried the following:

```
$.each(value, function(index, value){
   $("#myTable > thead").append("<a href='/query/"+value.account_id+"'><tr><td>"+value.first_name+"</td><td>"+value.address1+value.address2+value.address3+"</td></tr></a>");
});
```

It is working but it collapses my table or there is no table at all. It renders like paragraph. What's going wrong?

Comment: You need to get some insight into hoe `table`, `tr`, `td` etc. works.

Comment: He means "how". Just a typo :)
 Besides, the `thead` can contain only one row `<tr>`.

Comment: thead can only contain one <tr> so it's probably failing since you are trying to add another one to the head

Comment: the tbody to the same thing

Comment: @AdityaParab There's no limit on how many rows a thead can contain.

Comment: @Juhana: agreed. However, what kinda of semantic explanation can be given for having multiple rows in `thead`? Ofcourse, it will work that way but I am finding it hard to imagine a scenario where you'd need multiple rows in `thead`.

Comment: @AdityaParab Well for example https://jsfiddle.net/a17ax4L1/